# "ValueError: All arrays must be the same length" Python Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
import pandas as ps

jsonData = ps.read_json('/Users/kallesova/downloads/graphjunction/graph.json')

print(jsonData.to_string())
```

Im trying to get some json data imported to python with pandas but Im running into ValueError: All arrays must be the same length. What to do?
I am new to python and pandas.

Comment: Hello, can you share your data samples? It seems that there is inconsistency in your data

Comment: A slight recommendation, use the standard alias for pandas ("pd") instead of "ps". Not crucial, but clearer. And as @sudden_appearance notes, more detail is needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.